# How to print a PDF on a larger paper format

Tags: command-line, cups, lpr

I am trying to print a PDF document via the command line. The PDF has the format of a business card. The paper I am printing on is in A6 format.

I have tried the following command:

```
lpr -P <my_printer_name> -o media=A6 ./BusinessCard.pdf
```

The job is sent to the printer (HP Officejet Pro 8620). Then the printer displays the following error message:

> Selected print format does not match the paper format.

As soon as I confirm the error, the print job is deleted from the queue.

Is it possible to print a PDF with a smaller format than the paper loaded via the command line. I want the PDF to be printed in the upper left corner.

## EDIT

I went through the `lpstat lpinfo lpq lpadmin pdfinfo pdftk xpdf` man pages but could not find an option to overcome the format issue. Do I have to change my PDF before sending it to the printer?

Comment: Use `lpstat`, `lpinfo`, `lpq`, `lpadmin` commands (read the `man` pages), `http://localhost:631` for printer. `pdfinfo`, `pdftk`, `xpdf` for dealing with your PDF.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.